# Problems with a PEAR package on a local WAMP 3.0.4 32bit installation

Tags: php, package, wamp, pear

Windows 7 64bit
WAMP 3.0.4 323bit

I have WAMP working and have PEAR installed.

My strange situation starts when I try to install a PEAR package.

php is in C:\wamp32\bin\php\php5.6.19, where WAMP installed it.

I downloaded go-pear.phar from https://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar and put a copy in the php5.6.19 directory.

I then started a command prompt window, changed to the C:\wamp32\bin\php\php5.6.19 directory and entered:

php go-pear.phar

If you want it, I have all the output from that command command prompt window.

Short form - the PEAR installation seemed to complete with errors, the last line was:

> The 'pear' command is now at your service at c:\wamp32\bin\php\php5.6.19 \pear.bat

I want to install a package named Text_Highlighter.

At the command prompt I entered:

pear install Text_Highlighter

I got:

> Failed to download pear/text_highlighter within preferred state
>   "stable", latest release is version 0.7.3, stability "beta", use
>   channel://pear.php.net/text_highlighter-0.7.3" to install install
>   failed

I then tried:

pear install channel://pear.php.net/text_highlighter-0.7.3

I got (i formatted it as code instead of a quote because using a quote block did not wrap lines and it was impossible to read):

```
WARNING: "pear/XML_Parser" is deprecated in favor of "pear/XML_Parser2"
WARNING: "pear/Console_Getopt" is deprecated in favor of "pear/Console_GetoptPlu
s"
WARNING: "pear/Console_Getopt" is deprecated in favor of "pear/Console_GetoptPlu
s"
downloading Text_Highlighter-0.7.3.tgz ...
Starting to download Text_Highlighter-0.7.3.tgz (141,773 bytes)
..............................done: 141,773 bytes
downloading PEAR-1.10.1.tgz ...
Starting to download PEAR-1.10.1.tgz (296,139 bytes)
...done: 296,139 bytes
downloading XML_Parser-1.3.6.tgz ...
Starting to download XML_Parser-1.3.6.tgz (13,549 bytes)
...done: 13,549 bytes
downloading Console_Getopt-1.4.1.tgz ...
Starting to download Console_Getopt-1.4.1.tgz (5,672 bytes)
...done: 5,672 bytes
downloading Archive_Tar-1.4.2.tgz ...
Starting to download Archive_Tar-1.4.2.tgz (20,624 bytes)
...done: 20,624 bytes
downloading Structures_Graph-1.1.1.tgz ...
Starting to download Structures_Graph-1.1.1.tgz (12,579 bytes)
...done: 12,579 bytes
downloading XML_Util-1.3.0.tgz ...
Starting to download XML_Util-1.3.0.tgz (17,351 bytes)
...done: 17,351 bytes
install ok: channel://pear.php.net/Console_Getopt-1.4.1
install ok: channel://pear.php.net/Archive_Tar-1.4.2
install ok: channel://pear.php.net/Structures_Graph-1.1.1
install ok: channel://pear.php.net/XML_Util-1.3.0
install ok: channel://pear.php.net/PEAR-1.10.1
install ok: channel://pear.php.net/XML_Parser-1.3.6
install ok: channel://pear.php.net/Text_Highlighter-0.7.3
PEAR: Optional feature webinstaller available (PEAR's web-based installer)
PEAR: Optional feature gtkinstaller available (PEAR's PHP-GTK-based installer)
PEAR: Optional feature gtk2installer available (PEAR's PHP-GTK2-based installer)

PEAR: To install optional features use "pear install pear/PEAR#featurename"

C:\wamp32\bin\php\php5.6.19>
```

When that completed, I went to look at the directories and this is where it gets strange (at least to me)

The \wamp32\bin\php directory now has both a \php5.6.19 which is the one WAMP installed and it has \php5.6.15!!

The new directory has a \pear directory and that directory has a \Text directory - where it  installed the package - \wamp32\bin\php5.6.15\pear\Text

Why did the package installation create a new php directory - \wamp32\bin\php\php5.6.15 when I ran the pear install command in the \wamp32\bin\php\php5.6.19?

It looks like the install command:

pear install channel://pear.php.net/text_highlighter-0.7.3

installed PHP 5.6.15, PEAR, and the Text_Highlight package? Why?

What should I do to get the package installed in the \wamp32\php\php5.6.19\pear

A few days ago, I had done this installation, as I described above, without noticing that there was a new PHP directory.

I even wrote code to use the package and used the package from the new PHP directory, without realizing it.

I then had some trouble with WAMP and reinstalled it. Today I installed PEAR and the package as I described above.

This time I noticed that there was that new PHP directory and that the package was installed there, in the directory \Text

Recap:

WAMP installed PHP in \wamp32\bin\php\php5.6.19 I put the go-pear.phar file in that directory and ran it to install PEAR.

The "install package" created a new directory, \wamp32\php\php5.6.15 with a \pear subdirectory and a \Text subdirectory with the package in it.

In appears to have installed PHP, PEAR, and the package. Not just the package.

I just tried a little experiment -

I copied the \Text directory (the package directory) from \wamp32\php\php5.6.15\pear (the one the package install created) to \wamp32\php\php5.6.19\pear (which was created when I installed PEAR)

I then modified my PHP code to refer to the package files (changed the path in a require statement) in \wamp32\php\php5.6.19\pear\Text and ran it.

It works just fine.

I just downloaded the package file from the page https://pear.php.net/package/Text_Highlighter/download using a link to [http://download.pear.php.net/package/Text_Highlighter-0.7.3.tgz](https://pear.php.net/package/Text_Highlighter/download)

When I unarchived that file I get the same thing as was put in the \pear\Text directory by the package install.

Does this mean that installing a PEAR package is simply a matter of downloading it and putting it in subdirectory of the \pear directory?

It just seems there has to be more to it than that?

Can anyone explain this to me, please?

If you want to see the entire command prompt output from the start of installing PEAR to the end of the package install, let me know and I will edit this and add it.

Comment: I have an answer for one question I asked, whether PEAR packages can be downloaded and put in a directory manually, without PEAR, and used. The answer is yes. PEAR is simply a repository of packages with update features to maintain the packages as updates are made to them. To use the PEAR packages, they merely need to be in a directory somewhere so they can be "required" into your PHP code.

Comment: This question is unreadable.